# Problema com geração da chave primaria spring-boot-jpa

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, uuid

Estou criando um projetinho usando spring boot,mas ao utilizar a jpa do spring-boot-jpa estou enfrentando dificuldades:

```
org.springframework.data.relational.core.conversion.DbActionExecutionException: Failed to execute DbAction.InsertRoot(entity=br.com.voyager.central.model.Movie@640c216b, generatedId=null)
```

Bem esse e o resultado da execução de :

```
@Test
public void insert() {

    Movie filme = new Movie("Cachorros de novo").setDescription("A historia de um vira-lata");

    repository.save(filme);// <- Erro


}
```

Para adicionar as informações de maneira mais abrangente aqui esta a minha class Movie e a minha super MappedSuperclass:

- MappedSuperClass

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4231451612698516409L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
    protected UUID uuid;

    public Entity setUUID(@NonNull UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        return this;
    }

    public UUID getUUID() {
        return this.uuid;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // primeiro verifica se o outro object não é nulo
        if (object != null)
            if(object instanceof Entity)// Verificar se e uma intancia de um movie
                if (this.uuid.equals(((Entity)object).getUUID())) {// verificar se é o mesmo uuid
                    return true;
                }

        return false;
    }

}
```

- Classe Movie

```
@Entity
public class Movie extends br.com.voyager.central.model.Entity{

    /**
     * Serial da versãod a classe 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7743281799376449433L;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String midia;

    public Movie() {}
    public Movie(@NonNull String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Movie(@NonNull UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
    public Movie(@NonNull UUID uuid ,@NonNull String name) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Movie(@NonNull String uuid ,@NonNull String name) {
        this.uuid = UniqueIdentifier.getUUIDByString(uuid);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public Movie setDescription(@NonNull String desc) {
        this.description = desc;
        return this;
    }
    public String getMidia() {
        return midia;
    }
    public Movie setMidia(@NonNull String midia) {
        this.midia = midia;
        return this;
    }

    public Movie setName(@NonNull String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public Movie setUUID(@NonNull UUID uuid) {
        super.setUUID(uuid);
        return this;
    }


}
```

Notem que eu estou usando o UUID como identificador e as versões que eu estou usando:

- mysql-connector-java v5.1.48
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa v2.1.9.RELEASE

E o meu pom esta assim cavaleiros:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>br.com.voyager</groupId>
  <artifactId>central</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>central</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>2.1.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.6.Final</hibernate.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
       <version>5.1.48</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency> -->
  </dependencies>
  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Por favor me ajudem procurei em todo lugar por deixar essa geração automática vai ficar muito chato se eu tiver que gerar e atribuir um antes da inserção. Agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: O id precisa mesmo ser um UUID?

Comment: Sinceramente não ,mas prefiro que seja assim amigo

Comment: Poste a stacktrace completa por gentileza

Comment: Você se refere ao ponto aonde ocorre o erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O MySQL é um pouco mais chato para se trabalhar com UUID, esse link, [esse tutorial](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-guid-uuid-default-column/) mostra uma solução alternativa onde você cria um campo nulo, e uma trigger que preenche com um uuid automaticamente. Uma solução mais elegante seria, na sua Entity, criar um método com a anotação @PrePersist, e nesse método, gerar o UUID para ser gravado no banco. Assim:

```
@PrePersist
public void prePersist() {
    this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

A anotação `@PrePersist` é uma anotação especial do Hibernate que possibilita executar uma função antes de algum evento de banco de dados. No meu exemplo coloquei `@PrePersist`, mas para outras situações, existem anotações `@PreUpdate`, `@PostLoad`, enfim, várias. [Veja mais aqui nesse link.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html)

No entanto, seria interessante usar outro banco que trabalha melhor com isso, de repente a versão 8.0 do MySql, ou o PostgreSQL, que é mais robusto, e com melhores recursos. Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Amigo eu mudei para a versão 8 do mysql e usei também a sua anotação , mas nem um deles deu resultado o mesmo erro persiste

Comment: Estou tentando criar um converter na qual eu resolva o problema pois agora eu estou colocando o UUID na mão e na hora de pegar devolva ele apresenta um erro de byte[] para uuid [Imagem](https://prnt.sc/pjsytj)

Comment: Por quê de UUID para byte, e não para String?

Comment: Pare se que ta um erro quando digo que o campu UUID deve ser armazenado como varchar